# How to evaluate whether two number are close enough or not in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, floating-point-comparison

I have two numbers -

3.125000 Mbytes and 2.954880 Mbytes.

I want to compare them and it should return True since they are almost 3Mbytes. How can I do so in Python3.

I tried doing `math.isclose(3.125000,2.954880,  abs_tol=0.1)`.

However, this returns `False`. I really don't understand how to put tolerance here.

```
math.isclose(3.125000,2.954880,  abs_tol=0.1).
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

```
math.isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)
```

I am using Python 3.5.2.

The expected result is `True`.
The actual result is `False`.

Comment: The difference is more than 0.1, so not "close" enough.

Answer (score 4):

Your absolute tolerance is set to `0.1`, so the difference would have to be less than `0.1` to consider them equal; `3.125000 - 2.954880` is (rounded) `0.17012`, which is too big.

If you want them to be considered `close`, increase your tolerance a bit, e.g.:

```
math.isclose(3.125000, 2.954880, abs_tol=0.2)
```

which returns `True` as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The function `math.isclose` is really meant for dealing with floating-point imprecisions. You can use it for this, but you need to tune it appropriately: the numbers in your example are more than `0.1` apart.

If you're not worried about floating-point imprecisions, the better way to compare them is the obvious one:

```
def equivalent(a, b):
    return abs(a-b) < 0.1
```

Comment: It uses both, but it's considered "close" if *either* threshold is met; passing `abs_tol` of 0.1 is roughly equivalent to what you wrote, but would *also* allow truly huge numbers with small relative differences to be considered close as well.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yep, realized my mistake when I saw your answer. Edited so as not to mislead OP.